# I get a failure every time I try and execute this

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

**When I use Scanners or try to get a user input, I get the message:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':run'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date

When I just use a `system.out.println();`
It goes through successfully.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 *
 * @author boaz5
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nameString = name.next();
        System.out.println("Hi," + nameString);


    }

}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am a complete newbie and this is one of my first Java projects. Thanks!

Comment: please provide error details.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on here, but I can give a couple suggestions to get started:

1.) Update your Gradle plug-in. The compilation issue may not be code related, but instead a problem with the tooling.

2.) If above fails replace the IOException with Exception and see if we get any further output.

Let us know

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. The code is running without any error.
 I think you added the processor as a compile dependency. You should add it as '**provided**'.

Comment: How would you do that? Sorry but again, I'm really new to this. Using the Netbeans 11.2 IDE.

Comment: Check the link. Find the Gradle or Maven configuration.
https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick/blob/master/README.md#download

Answer (score 0):

you should review your environment, I did copy your code and work for me.

12:26:02 AM: Executing task 'Test.main()'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes
>
> Task :Test.main()
> What is your name?
> Alvaro
> Hi,Alvaro

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See